# How to set gnome todo to use todo.txt

Tags: gnome, 20.10

Ive seen various issues talking about a gnome todo -> todo.txt integration in the gnome gitlab and various other sources online referring to the integration but i cant figure out how to set it up. When i go to add a new list to gnome todo i only have one storage location ("this computer"). and other guides mention clicking on the "gnome todo icon in the top left corner" to change extensions but i don't see that icon anywhere.

How do i setup gnome-todo to integrate with todo.txt?

Answer (score 0):

The other backend/provider "plugins" including todo.txt are disabled by default:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-todo/-/blob/master/meson_options.txt#L7

and that means you'd have to compile it yourself (quite a few dependencies, and figuring these out, for me it failed with an error).

I don't know if building the "plugins" would enable a menu where one could select them. It could be done in `dconf-editor` (GUI) or `gsettings`:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.todo default-provider
'local'
$ gsettings range org.gnome.todo default-provider
type s
$ gsettings describe org.gnome.todo default-provider
The identifier of the default provider to add new lists to
```

This applies to Ubuntu 22.04 and

```
$ apt show gnome-todo
Package: gnome-todo
Version: 3.28.1-6ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: gnome
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers <pkg-gnome-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 485 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4), libecal-2.0-1 (>= 3.33.4), libedataserver-1.2-26 (>= 3.33.4), libedataserverui-1.2-3 (>= 3.33.4), libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 0.9.2), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.51.2), libgoa-1.0-0b (>= 3.5.1), libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.21.5), libical3 (>= 3.0.0), libjson-glib-1.0-0 (>= 1.5.2), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libpeas-1.0-0 (>= 1.17), librest-0.7-0 (>= 0.7), gnome-todo-common (>= 3.28.1-6ubuntu1), libgnome-todo (= 3.28.1-6ubuntu1), evolution-data-server (>= 3.17.1), gsettings-desktop-schemas
Breaks: gnome-todo-common (<< 3.28)
Replaces: gnome-todo-common (<< 3.28)
Homepage: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Todo
Task: ubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-desktop-raspi
Download-Size: 165 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: no
APT-Sources: http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
Description: minimalistic personal task manager designed to fit GNOME desktop
 GNOME To Do is a simplistic personal task manager designed to perfectly fit
 the GNOME desktop. Designed from ground up to seamlessly integrate with
 the GNOME desktop environment, To Do enables you to be as productive as
 you want.
```

Related: [gnome-todo (Ubuntu "To Do") lacks help, how does it store lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414278/)