# gnome-todo (Ubuntu "To Do") lacks help, how does it store lists?

Tags: gnome, 22.04

I would like to know where and how "To Do" stores the lists, but the burger menu is disabled and it (`gnome-todo`) does not even have a `--version` option. But here it is:

```
~$ apt show gnome-todo
Package: gnome-todo
Version: 3.28.1-6ubuntu1
...
```

There is no man page.

I don't see any further info on its homepage either:

- https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Todo

Nor in the project wiki:

- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-todo

There is an old (2y) issue about the lack of documentation, not a single comment from the maintainers:

- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-todo/-/issues/288

Comment: You are right, so I removed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the `local` storage: `/home/<user>/.local/share/evolution/tasks/<id>/tasks.ics` and `/home/<user>/.local/share/evolution/tasks/system/tasks.ics` for "Personal"

Running `$ gnome-todo -d` prints

```
23:28:38.0742       GtdProviderSelector:    DEBUG: Adding provider local
23:28:38.0761            GtdProviderEds:    DEBUG: Task list 'Personal' successfully connected
23:28:38.0761            GtdProviderEds:    DEBUG: Task list 'test' successfully connected
23:28:38.0818            GtdTaskListEds:    DEBUG: ECalClientView for tasklist 'Personal' successfully acquired
23:28:38.0819            GtdTaskListEds:    DEBUG: ECalClientView for tasklist 'test' successfully acquired
23:28:38.0833            GtdTaskListEds:    DEBUG: Personal: GNOME To Do API version 1
23:28:38.0837            GtdTaskListEds:    DEBUG: test: GNOME To Do API version 1
```

Searching for https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-todo/search?q=%22Adding+provider%22 leads to https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-todo/blob/master/src/gui/gtd-provider-selector.c#L273

If you dig around, there should be several more "providers", e.g. "todo.txt", so I assume this is a buggy package.

---

Edit

Also see https://askubuntu.com/a/1272813/1029310

`/home/<user>/.config/evolution/sources/system-task-list.source` contains the configuration of the "Personal" task list.

---

Edit

The other "providers" are disabled by default and would require building from source. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1415059/1029310